# Find all elements $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ of order 2, so that $a+a\equiv 0\pmod {20}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find all elements $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ of order 2, so that $a+a\equiv 0\pmod {20}$

What do I do since it says a+a? Because to find the order I need to do like $2^1$=2 and whatnot, right?

Comment: When you say "to do like $2^1=2$ and whatnot", it sounds like you're trying to find the order of the element $2$ under multiplication. This is not what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking you to find all elements of order $2$ in the additive group $\Bbb Z_{20}$. In particular, it is asking you to find all $a$ such that $a\neq 0$ but $2a=0$ (which is to say $a+a=0$).

Comment: So if a=10, then I would have 0 mod 20?

Comment: If $a=10$, then $a+a=0$ mod $20$, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In a group $G$ the order or an element $g$ is the smallest natural number (not $0$) such that $g^n = e$ where $e$ is the identity in the group.

The group $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is a groun under addition, so here the order of an element $m$ is the smallest $n$ such that $nm = 0$.

Try to compute $2m$ for all $m\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$:
$$
\begin{align}
2\cdot 1 &= 1 \neq 0 \\
2\cdot 2 &= 4 \neq 0 \\
2\cdot 3 &= 6 \neq 0 \\
&\vdots  \\
2\cdot 8 &= 16 \neq 0 \\
&\vdots \\
2\cdot 11 &= 2 \neq 0 \\
2 \cdot 15 &= 10 \neq 0 \\
&\vdots 
\end{align}
$$

The elements of order $2$ are exactly those where this product is equal to $0$.

Comment: so my answer would only be when a=10?

Comment: @ematth7: Very good.

Comment: would a=20 also be an answer?

Comment: @ematth7: No, $20 = 0$ and $0$ has order $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Find all $a\ne 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $2a$ a multiple of $20$ and reduce $\pmod {20}.$ The remaining element is  $a\equiv 10 \pmod {20}$

Answer (score 0):

$a+a\equiv 0\bmod {20}$ iff $20$ divides $2a$ iff $10$ divides $a$.

So $a\equiv0$ and $a\equiv10$ are the only solutions of $a+a\equiv 0\bmod {20}$.

However, $a\equiv0$ does not have order $2$, and so  the only element of order $2$ is $a\equiv10$.

Comment: why is $a\equiv 0$ an answer?

Comment: @ematth7, sorry, missed that, fixed. thanks.